# Find a bulk fallback image solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, on every image I have something like this:

```html
<img src="img/hello.svg" onerror="this.src='img/hello.png';this.onerror=null;">
```

Is it possible to make page wide code which automatically switches from .svg, to a different format if an error occurs?

I think... I saw a solution like I've described maybe a year ago... but I've searched far and wide and had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` selecting all images whose `src` attributes end in `.svg`, and add an event listener on each of them:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".svg"]').forEach(function(el) {
    console.log('el');
    el.addEventListener('error', changeImage);
  });
});

function changeImage(e) {
  e.target.src = e.target.src.slice(0, -4) + '.png';
  e.target.removeEventListener('error', changeImage);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/hello.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just iterate over all `img`s which end in `.svg` and attach `error` handlers to them:

```
document.querySelectorAll('img[src$=".svg"]')
  .forEach((img) => {
    function errorListener () {
      img.removeEventListener('error', errorListener);
      img.src = img.src.replace(/src$/, 'png');
    }
    img.addEventListener('error', errorListener);
  });
```